# Adding an arrayList of random type to an arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have looked a lot online on how to do this and what I get is this

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Type>> arrayLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Type>>();
ArrayList<TypeA> typeA = new ArrayList<TypeA>();
ArrayList<TypeB> typeB = new ArrayList<TypeB>();
...
```

Assuming that I have a class called TypeA, and a class called TypeB, and the array list typeA would contain multiple objects of the class TypeA. The same goes for typeB

Now my question what do I put where Type is for the arrayList, and how do I add an arrayList to arrayLists? If I did this I would get an error:

```
arrayLists.add(typeA);
```

I am trying to make a list that contains arrayLists, if my approach is wrong please tell me.

Comment: I think you should mention whether typeA and typeB are related or not I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an ArrayList which contains ArrayLists with unknown contents, use the type `ArrayList<ArrayList<?>>` for the outer list.

This code should compile with no problems:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<?>> arrayLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<?>>();
ArrayList<TypeA> typeA = new ArrayList<TypeA>();
ArrayList<TypeB> typeB = new ArrayList<TypeB>();

arrayLists.add(typeA);
arrayLists.add(typeB);
```

Comment: I did not ask this question but can you explain a little more so I can vote u up?

Comment: ? is a wildcard, not much explaining needed :)